# Can't get russian letters in EXIF

Tags: objective-c, utf-8, character-encoding, nsstring, exif

example 1  - it works

```
NSString *first = @"Russian letters(Русские буквы)";
[exifDictionary setValue:first  forKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyExifUserComment];
```

example 2 - doesn't work

```
NSString *rus = @"Русские буквы";
NSString *first;
first = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Russian letters(%@)",rus]; 

[exifDictionary setValue:first  forKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyExifUserComment];
```

In second case in EXIF write "Russian letters(??????? ?????)"
if NSString contains parameter its happens.
how can I get correct russian letters use NSString with parameter?

maybe problem is the next saving at dictionary?

```
[exifDictionary setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Russian letters(%@)",rus]  forKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyExifUserComment];
```

or

```
[exifDictionary setValue:first  forKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyExifUserComment];
```

Comment: You should be making your strings like this: NSString *bacon = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Russian stuff here"];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using UTF8 hard-coded strings in code isn't safe.
See apple's article about [Formatting String Objects](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000943).

I suppose that you can use that code as workaround:

```
NSString *rus = @"Русские буквы";
NSString *formatString = [NSString initWithUTF8String:"Russian letters(%@)"];
NSString *first = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:formatString, rus];
```

Or if that doesn't work either, so, you can always use plain C to perform formatting:

```
NSString *rus = @"Русские буквы";
char buffer[128];
snprintf(buffer, 128, "Russian letters(%s)", [rus cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8Encoding]);
NSString *first = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:buffer];
```

Comment: _NSString *formatString = [NSString initWithUTF8String:"Russian letters(%@)"];_  gives warning, i try so  _NSString *formatString = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:"Russian letters(%@)"];_ - but it dont work anyway, result the same. and second one:   snprintf(buffer, 128, "Russian letters(%s)", [rus cStringUsingEncoding:**NSUTF8StringEncoding**]); the same..  thx for link, at the moment read it.