# How do you write the degrees symbol (°) into EXIF on iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios6, exif

I'm struggling to write a string into a JPG's Exif: user comments section, that contains the degress symbol (°).

But it constantly writes out a '?' character in its place.

ex.

```
NSString *xmlData = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:"°,\xC2\xB0,\u00b0"];
[EXIFDictionary setObject:xmlData forKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyExifUserComment];
```

Results in:

```
?,?,?
```

This doesn't work either:

```
NSString *xmlData = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"43, °, \xC2\xB0, \u00b0, 21'45\""];
```

NSLog displays the '°' of course. But when I use an EXIF viewer to actually read the data saved within the JPG, it still comes out as '?'.

Some more info.
Once the properties are written, ex.

```
[metadataAsMutable setObject:EXIFDictionary forKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary];
```

The result from NSLog looks like this:

```
UserComment = "43, \U00b0, \U00b0, \U00b0, 21'45\"";
```

Has anyone had success with this?

Comment: have you tried simply as string no utf8/16 etc

Comment: How are you printing the result?

Comment: `\Unnnn` is the usual NSLog output for non-ASCII characters in a dictionary, so `\U00b0` is the same as `°`. - I *assume* that the problem is that EXIF does not have a defined encoding. Perhaps iOS writes the comment as UTF-8 and your EXIF viewer interprets it as something else or displays all non-ASCII characters as "?".

Comment: I have tried a variety of EXIF viewers on the iPhone and desktop, and they all report the same way it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug or unsupported in the ImageIO framework.

The Exif specification (http://www.exif.org/Exif2-2.PDF) states that the UserComment tag
starts with a 8-byte area specifying the encoding and can be *ASCII*, *JIS*, *Unicode* or *Undefined*.

If I set a UserComment using ExifTool (on OS X):

```
exiftool -UserComment="30°" test.jpg
```

and inspect the file "test.jpg" with a hex editor, I find the 
following data for the UserComment tag:

```
55 4e 49 43 4f 44 45 00     // UNICODE id
00 33 00 30 00 b0           // "30°" as (big-endian) UTF-16
```

On the other hand, if I use the code from your older question [Modified EXIF data doesn't save properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12869706/modified-exif-data-doesnt-save-properly) to set
the same UserComment, I find the following data:

```
41 53 43 49 49 00 00 00     // ASCII id
33 30 3F                    // "30?" in ASCII encoding
```

This means that ImageIO/CoreGraphics uses only the ASCII encoding to save UserComment tags
and converts all non-ASCII characters to a question mark.

Comment: Your clarifying example is brilliant.  And explains why this hack works: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8505114/7599
So what remains is for me to try and convert my NSString text into ASCII now and hope the results stick.

Comment: No success.  All of my hacking still did not result in the degree symbol being saved in ASCII format.

Comment: @SebastianDwornik: I don't see how the code from your linked answer could help (and I have the impression that the answer was accepted even if it did not solve the problem.) - The problem is that `CGImageDestinationAddImageFromSource` does not handle non-ASCII characters in the Exif UserComment correctly. And the degree symbol is not an ASCII character, so "saving the degree symbol in ASCII format" does not make sense. - I am afraid that there is no solution using the ImageIO framework on iOS.